# Set font for UIButton with extension

Tags: swift

I want to make it easy to change fonts and colors throughout my app. I have made a extension for `UIButton` like this:

```
extension UIButton {

    func cancelAndSaveButtons() {

        backgroundColor = Theme.tintColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
        layer.shadowRadius = 5
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
        setTitleColor(Theme.mainFontColor, for: .normal)
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Theme.mainButtonFont, size: 25)

    }
  }
```

And I have a `class` for the Theme:

```
class Theme {
    static let mainFontName = "BrushScriptMT"
    static let mainButtonFont = "FredokaOne"
    static let accentColor = UIColor(named: "Accent")
    static let backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Background")
    static let tintColor = UIColor(named: "Tint")
    static let mainFontColor = UIColor(named: "MainFontColor")

}
```

However, when I call `myButton.cancelAndSaveButtons()`in `viewDidLoad` the font or fontSize do not change.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using the wrong font name. Add this code to your `AppDelegate` and check if you're using the right name:

```
for fontFamilyName in UIFont.familyNames {
        print("family: \(fontFamilyName)\n")

        for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontFamilyName) {
            print("font: \(fontName)")
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

This is even cooler to print out the fonts:

```
dump(UIFont.familyNames)
```

Also, double check if you have imported your font files and added them to your plist. The font names on your plist must be the same as they will be printed on the code above.

Comment: It was a misspell.. Thanks